# How would I create a clean version of this logo?

Tags: logo, image-trace

A client wants a cleaner version of the logo attached. Essentially I have to use this logo but I don't have an editable file only the PNG provided. At the moment I'm stuck on how to trace over the image to create a cleaner version. I have tried to use Image Trace but it doesn't seem to work to well.

Any suggestions would be appreciated as I'm honestly at a loss on how to recreate this.[image]

Comment: Either find the font used (Probably you wont have success with that as it looks custom made or at least adjusted a lot). Or you trace it manually in Illustrator. There's no quick fix for this. Or it may also be that the client has got a pdf containing the logo as vector that could be extracted.

Comment: Is the image you added in the question the largest size you've got?

Comment: I have sometimes had to deal with this when working on "program ad books" for events. One trick which works well for for some subset of these is to look online for a published PDF that was produced professionally: a menu, a prospectus, a brochure. It is often possible to extract a high-resolution for-print version of the logo from these PDFs. It is fairly easy (and quick) to check for this online and saves a lot of time over trying to remake the asset.

Comment: The font is called [Wilmington BF](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bomparte/wilmington-bf/regular/). It looks like the S has been turned upside down, but this might be a Unicode alternate glyph.

Comment: @r3mainer - well spotted. Looks very similar. Yeah the S has been flipped.

Comment: It can also be *really* helpful to determine the font first... use https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ or https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator for that.

Comment: Great find  @r3mainer !

Answer (score 17):

You can get a reasonable trace of the Sabella lettering if you open the PNG in Photoshop, engage the alpha lock then fill it black. Export as PNG again. Then import this back into Illustrator and trace it. Here's the trace and settings I used.

[image]

It won't trace the small text well, so you can just expand and ungroup the trace, delete the wonky small text and retype "INTERIORS" with Times New Roman or some similar serif font, same font size, and increase kerning to match the original.

You might need to fix some of the curves on the traced text manually, but shouldn't be too difficult.

Note: if you don't have Illustrator or Photoshop, the same could be done using free software such as GIMP and Inskcape.

Another possibility:

You could manually redraw all the letters with the Pen Tool (aka Bézier tool), using the image as a guide to trace over the top.

I've included an example here showing the start of this process, but using Inkscape this time (also possible in Illustrator). Obviously this is time consuming and requires a degree of skill with the Bézier tool, and some manual tweaking of curves, but it's entirely possible. Also, without the actual original font, it's probably the best way to get an almost perfect result.

[image]

Comment: Ahh thank you! That seems to have worked really well

Comment: @Lauren: What, specifically, seems to have worked really well?

Comment: @dotancohen - When Lauren posted the comment, I had only answered with the image tracing. The part that shows how to redraw was added in a later edit.

Answer (score 6):

Ask your client to give you the largest image file they have and pass it through the Image Trace in Illustrator. If you cannot find a large enough image to produce good results, upscale it in Photoshop first, add some sharpening to make the edges a bit clearer and try again. You might still need to do some tweaks in the curves generated, the tool will just get you close enough that you don't have to retrace the whole thing from scratch.

Alternatively, try to find a handwritten font similar enough (that shouldn't be so hard), convert it to curves and tweak it to match the logo. I'd avoid that though since it might take you some time.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool called [VectorMagic](https://de.vectormagic.com/), it can easily give you a decent vector graphic of this or any rasterized logo without gradients.